# Does Everyauth's workflow support 3rd party app authorization?

Tags: node.js, oauth

That is, showing users the Allow/Deny page rather than just authenticating with Twitter account. TBH, not sure if there's a distinction but the examples and other docs I've found so far don't mention this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The allow / deny page is always surfaced on the other end (Twitter, Facebook, etc. will render this page) rather than on your end.

Comment: Right, I understand the deferral part but I'm not clear if there's a difference between authorizing an app and authenticating for an app.

Comment: There isn't really, the authentication is handled internally via the credentials passed from the provider.